# Appending "Copy" before extension of filename when copying files

Tags: java, file, copy

Let's say the source file name is `Foo.txt`. I want the name of the destination file to be `Foo(Copy).txt`. And I want the source file to be preserved. How do I go about accomplishing this?

```
/*
 * Returns a copy of the specified source file
 * 
 * @param sourceFile the specified source file
 * @throws IOException if unable to copy the specified source file
 */
public static final File copyFile(final File sourceFile) throws IOException 
{
    // Construct the destination file
    final File destinationFile = .. // TODO: Create copy file
    if(!destinationFile.exists()) 
    {
        destinationFile.createNewFile();
    }

    // Copy the content of the source file into the destination file
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try 
    {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(source != null) 
        {
            source.close();
        }
        if(destination != null) 
        {
            destination.close();
        }
    }

    return destinationFile;
}
```

Comment: Aside from just using Commons IO `FileUtils` like a sensible person?

Comment: Another handy way is to use the Ant CopyTask: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Copy.java.html

Comment: how was skaffman's comment uncalled for or did I miss something?

Comment: It wasn't snide (at least, it wasn't intended to be). Writing this sort of stuff by hand is, in my opinion, foolish, unless there's a very good reason that you can't use Commons IO.

Comment: @mre I would hardly call the comment skaffman made snide. What is more telling is that you have been on this site for over a year have 13k+ reputation, are active in Java questions and did not think to look at Apache Commons for what is undoubtedly a common task before posting this question on the site.  In my opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
String name = sourceFile.getName();
int i = name.contains(".") ? name.lastIndexOf('.') : name.length();
String dstName = name.substring(0, i) + "(Copy)" + name.substring(i);
File dest = new File(sourceFile.getParent(), dstName);
```

Comment: @ZackMacomber, should be `sourceFile`. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

There is a convenience method in Google's Guava library [Files.copy(File, File)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#copy%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) .